# Listbox multiselect losing focus with OnKeyUp

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-5, onkeyup

I have Two listboxes and both with Multiselect:=True. I have a popup menu that Copy/Paste to/from the Clipboard for the selected items. All works as intended.

I wanted to add keyboard CtrlC (Copy) and Ctrl+V (Paste) but after selecting items, then using Ctrl-C, the Selected items all lose selection and the first item in the list is selected and it gets copied to the Clipboard.

I am using the KeyPreview and main form OnKeyUp

```
if (ssCtrl in Shift) then
begin
  case Char(Key) of
   'c','C' : puCopyClick(Sender);
   'v','V' : puPasteClick(Sender);
  end;
  Exit;
end;
case Key of
  VK_Delete : puDeleteClick(Self);
end;
Exit;
```

How can I make the Ctrl+C etc work as the popup does?

Thanks

Comment: According to your previous question, there is no keyboard and only the mouse and so this question makes no sense. Aside from that, what made you select `OnKeyUp`? That's the wrong event. Just have a look at how other apps behave. Shortcut keys fire when the key goes down. Would you like us to help you learn how to do all of this properly? Judging from your previous question it seems that you don't want to do it right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You seem to leap to conclusions **a lot.** I didn't say there was no keyboard, I said I was forcing them to use the mouse. The reason being I am doing this to help semi-automate a friend's failing business and at less than a buck-an-hour, **I will** dictate what is the right way to do **this** stuff. I have been programming for a long time, probably before you were born, (assumption based on apparent arrogance) so please do not offer to teach me "properly" when you only understand 5% of the situation.

Comment: How are they going to press CTRL+C when you force them to use the mouse? If you want to assume that focus is changed only by use of the mouse, that is up to you. But it's an erroneous assumption. I cannot force you to do it the right way. If you believe that `OnMouseUp` is the correct way to detect focus change, then that is up to you. But I do believe that you would benefit from opening your mind to the possibility that you are wrong. Of course, I could be wrong too. I don't have all the information.

Comment: Also, what does it matter when you started programming. So what if it was before I was born? I've got ~200k rep here. Does that make me right? Of course not. I could be talking absolute rubbish. I frequently do. You should judge statements for their own merits. Anytime someone tries to assert that they are right because they are older and more experienced, I get suspicious. There are teenagers who can program better than I can, and 40 year veterans who are hopeless.

Comment: An explanation of the behavior you've observed in your program: Before your key-up event handler ever runs, the built-in key-down handler of the control is seeing the keystroke and attempting to select the item in the list that starts with *C*, which apparently is the first item in the list. Afterward, your key-up handler copies the newly changed selection to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle shortcut keys is to let the menu items handle them. You say that you have a popup menu that has these actions. Use the `Shortcut` property of the menu item to associate that menu item with the shortcut key.

That allows you to remove all the manual keyboard event handling and let the framework do it for you. That has many benefits. Not least of which is that the event will fire when the key goes down rather than when it goes up as you currently have it.

Even better would be to use actions which if I recall correctly do exist in Delphi 5. These allow you to associate a single *action*, for example *copy to clipboard* with multiple independent UI elements. For example that action can be associated with a main menu, a popup menu, and a shortcut key.

Comment: Thanks David, I had overlooked the key-shortcuts. The other suggestion "even better" requires more work than I care to invest in this project : To see why, see Comment above. :)

Comment: Usually the use of actions result in less work than the alternatives.